# How do I correctly use initialization syntax to initialize a struct?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I would like to ZeroMem a struct using the initialization syntax present in the new C++11. Currently I am doing this:

```
Mesh::Mesh(void) :
    m_bInitialized(false),
    m_BoundingBox(BoundingBox()), // <-- Is this right???
    m_numVertices(0),
    m_pVertexInfos(nullptr),
    m_pFaceIndices(nullptr),
    m_numFaces(0),
    m_numFacesIndices(0),
    m_materialIndex(0),
    m_faceType(NONE)
{
}
```

Which seems to do the trick, but it just looks kind of ugly and doesn't feel right. Is there a better way?

I was under the impression that what made this initialization syntax so good is that it somehow automagically initialized the memory block that made up the class without wasting more CPU cycles than it would other wise and having a constructor in the syntax would defeat that purpose.

On that note, if someone can explain to me what makes it so good or link me to an article that explains it, I would appreciate it.

Thanks for reading

Comment: The only C++11 I see is `nullptr`. And you can replace `BoundingBox()` with `{}` in situations where you need to put something. Here, you actually don't need to put anything there.

Comment: Don't perform premature optimization, C++ is **fast.** How is this looking wrong?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was a new C++11 feature but it apparently is not. Consider me not well versed in C++'s changelog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just say `m_BoundingBox()`. This will value-initialize the member, which means default-construct for class types and zero-initialize for scalar types.